# Is the bidual of a C*-algebra isomorphic to the universal enveloping von Nemann algebra as a Banach algebra?

Tags: c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, universal-property, module-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra and $(\pi, H)$ a universal representation of $A$.
We know that there is a linear isomorphism $\tilde{\pi}$ between the  bidual $A^{**}$ of $A$ and  the universal enveloping von Neumann algebra $M(\pi):=\pi(A)^{''}$.

> $A^{**}$ is a Banach algebra with *Arens product* $*$. 
>   Is $\tilde{\pi}$ an algebra isomorphism between $A^{**}$ and $M(\pi)$?

Comment: Short answer is yes, this follows from the fact that the Arens product coincides with the usual product on $A$ and some standard approximation arguments. I don't have time to spell it out.

Comment: Get it! It is sufficient to verify that two products coincide on $A$.